# counting number of same values and printing them in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a vector with repeated numbers. I want to count the number of repeated numbers and print the output.

This is my input:

```
deg <- c(2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1, 2)
df <- data.frame(table(deg))
```

This is my output:

```
   deg Freq
1   1    2
2   2    6
3   3    1
4   4    2
5   5    1
```

Here in my output I want to print the data frame from 0 to 5, where 0 is the starting element and 5 is the max element in the vector. The output I want to get is:

```
   deg Freq
1   0    0
2   1    2
3   2    6
4   3    1
5   4    2
6   5    1
```

Someone please help with this!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(deg=seq(0,max(deg)),
                 Freq=sapply(seq(0,max(deg)),function(x) length(which(deg==x))))
```

Output:

```
  deg Freq
1   0    0
2   1    2
3   2    6
4   3    1
5   4    2
6   5    1
```

Comment: Very neat! Can I recommend `df <- data.frame(deg=seq(0,max(deg)),Freq=sapply(seq(0,max(deg)),function(x) length(which(deg==x))))` so that it works as a general solution for any vector, (for e.g. `deg = c(2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1, 2, 7)`)

Answer (score 1):

If we're starting from `df` we can just unpack the data, add zero as a factor level, then re-tabulate:

```
f <- with(df, factor(rep(deg, Freq), levels = union(0, levels(deg))))
as.data.frame(table(deg = f))
#   deg Freq
# 1   0    0
# 2   1    2
# 3   2    6
# 4   3    1
# 5   4    2
# 6   5    1
```

If we're starting with the vector `deg`, it's easier.  We can just add zero as a factor level then tabulate:

```
f <- factor(deg, levels = union(0, sort(unique(deg))))
as.data.frame(table(deg = f))
#   deg Freq
# 1   0    0
# 2   1    2
# 3   2    6
# 4   3    1
# 5   4    2
# 6   5    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a row to `df`:

```
#convert deg from factor back to numeric 
df$deg = as.numeric(as.character(df$deg))

# add 0 deg with 0 freq if it doesn't exist already in df
if (!any(df$deg == 0)) {
    df = rbind(df, c(0,0))

    # sort df by deg
    df = df[order(df$deg),]
}
```

Comment: What if there is 0 in my "deg" array? will it return 0 deg and 1 freq ?

Comment: My original answer would, but I edited my answer to only add it if doesn't exist already.

Comment: I'm getting the below error:Error in df$deg : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: You ran your part first: 
`deg = c(2,1,4,3,2,4,2,5,2,2,1,2)`
`df = as.data.frame(table(deg))`
And then ran my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
rbind(data.frame(deg=0, Freq=0)[!(c(0) %in% deg)], as.data.frame(table(deg)))

  # deg Freq
# 1   0    0
# 2   1    2
# 3   2    6
# 4   3    1
# 5   4    2
# 6   5    1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `expand_df` function below can help you get the desired output

```
deg = c(2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1, 2)
df = as.data.frame(table(deg))

expand_df = function(df){
  upd_list = 0: max(as.numeric(as.character(df[,1])))
  upd_df = as.data.frame(upd_list)
  merged_df = merge(upd_df, df,all.x=TRUE,by.x=colnames(upd_df)[1], by.y=colnames(df)[1])
  merged_df[,2] = ifelse(is.na(merged_df[,2]),0,merged_df[,2])
  merged_df
}


expand_df(df)
```